# calculate 3 days rolling average in sql stored in Google Big Query

Tags: sql

My data is stored in Google Big QUery in a database. This is how my table looks like.

```
IP         Age Sex    Province  Epid_ID
19/05/2020 43  Female Bagmati   KTM-20-00206
18/05/2020 33  Male   Province1 KTM-20-00205
18/05/2020 30  Male   Province1 KTM-20-00204
18/05/2020 32  Male   Province1 KTM-20-00203
18/05/2020 63  Male   Province1 KTM-20-00202
17/05/2020 33  Male   Province2 KTM-20-00201
17/05/2020 23  Male   Province2 KTM-20-00200
16/05/2020 22  Male   Province2 KTM-20-00199
16/05/2020 23  Male   Province2 KTM-20-00198
```

Here, EpiD_ID is my unique ID. I want to calculate 3 days rolling average for each date. Following is my expected output.

```
Date      Count_Epid_ID  2_days_rolling_avg
16/05/2020  2                 0
17/05/2020  2                 0
18/05/2020  4                 2.66
19/05/2020  1                 2.33
```

Explanation: 0 for the first 2 days and we start calculating the rolling average from the 3rd day. For 18/05/2020, 2.66= (2+2+4)/3, 2.33 = (2+4+1)/3

I tried to use the following question.  However, I was not successful.

This is the Query I wrote which would only give me count of epid and not rolling average.

> SELECT
> IP,
> COUNT(*) AS `num`,
> FROM
> `interim-data.casedata.Interim Reloaded`
> GROUP BY
> IP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use window functions -- assuming you have data on every day:

```
SELECT IP, COUNT(*) AS num,
       AVG(COUNT(*)) OVER (ORDER BY IP ROWS BETWEEN 2 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW)
FROM interim-data.casedata.Interim Reloaded
GROUP BY IP;
```

It seems strange that a column called `IP` has a date value, but that seems to be how your data is modelled.

Comment: How does it work with the first two rows? I want to make the first two rows to be 0 and start average from the third row.

Comment: @pari . . . It produces the average with the rows that are available.  You can add a `case when row_number() . . . >= 3 then` if you really want `NULL` values for the first two.

Comment: I have slightly changed as I need the data by province and the latest data at top. SELECT
  IP, 
  COUNT(*) AS `num`,
  AVG(COUNT(*)) OVER (ORDER BY IP ROWS BETWEEN 7 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) as `rolling_average`,
FROM
  `interim-data.casedata.Interim Reloaded` 
  where Admin_Level_1_province = 'Province 1'
GROUP BY
  IP order by IP desc     This doesn't give any error. However, the result I am getting is not sorted according to the date. It starts with 2020 but 2021 is somewhere inside. I do not get this problem if I do not choose province.

Comment: @pari . . . The ordering of the results is determined by the `order by` clause in the query, not in the window function.  You need to explicitly include that.  If you need additional help with this, perhaps you should ask a *new* question.